# NodeJs Error: Port already in use:3000 using socket.io and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, port

I'm making a node.js application that uses socket.io and express.

The code looks like this-

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const http=require('http').Server(app);
app.use(express.static('public'));

const io=require('socket.io')(http,{
  cors:{origin:'*'}
});

http.listen(3000,()=>{
  console.log('listening to port 3000');
});

//when connection made 
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  console.log('connection made!');
});
```

Here,public is a folder container all the html files for the website.

Now,when I run it locally on my pc,it works fine
But when I deployed it on the glitch.com servers,i get this error:

```
Error: listen EADDREINUSE: address already in use :::3000
```

As far as i know,3000 is the only available port in glitch and I cannot use another port.

Also,the questions on stack overflow related to this topic doesn't help me since most of the answers are related to killing the running tasks themselves and I don't have permission to do so on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when your server is still running in error, try switching listening to 3001 and see if there is still the error

Comment: Only the port 3000 is available for glitch

Comment: try to run this `taskkill /f /im node.exe`

Comment: Doesn't help either

Answer (score 0):

free your 3000 port:

Linux: fuser -k 3000/tcp

Comment: Don't have permission to that on the glitch.com server where I'm hosting

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://support.glitch.com/t/listen-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-3000/9101/5) on glitch.com's forums you might have two services listening to the same port, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

You should also be able to change the default listening port by setting the `PORT` environment variable in your **.env** file if you have one. Trying a different port should solve the problem

**EDIT:**
Apparently the problem could be the initial configuration of the server, you can try setting everything up like this:

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app); <--
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', () => { /* your code */ });

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {/* your code */});
```

(Got this from [socket.io github page](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#express-3x))

If this doesn't work either you should try asking on [glitch.com's support forums](https://support.glitch.com/), one of their technicians will help you better troubleshoot your problem, they have all the necessary tools

Comment: There lies the problem
I can't change ports since glitch only allows one port to be accessed globally (which is 3000). If you think I can use any other NodeJs server,please suggest me

Comment: Also,I've condensed the code here to what's important. You can check the full code here https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ping-pong01

Comment: @Rajjaiswal from what I understand 3000 is just the default port and you can change it with your env file, but I've never used glitch.com. I'll check your code

Comment: @Rajjaiswal I tried your code and it doesn't appear to have any problems with port duplicates. I suggest you try two things: `console.log(process.env.PORT)` on the first line, this should tell you which port is enabled. Then try to change it by setting up an environment in your project (create a file named `.env` in the root of the project and write `PORT=8080` or whatever port you want to try, glitch should automatically switch(you need to install dotenv from npm and require() it in your code))

Comment: Tried it and obtained the same error,but for port 8080 this time

Comment: @Rajjaiswal I think i found the problem, i'm updating the answer with some code you can try

Comment: Oh I've done it finally. It turns out,there was no error in the server code. I just had the wrong parameters when connecting client using io() function. Also,the error was because the project was already running and i tried re-running it that caused the error. Sorry for wasting your time and being so dumb.

Comment: @Rajjaiswal oh, don't worry, things like this happen to me everytime hahahahaha, glad you found out in the end